# Having problems with datatables and firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, datatable

I'm using reactjs with firebase and having problems with the datatables.

```
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('items').orderByChild("item_name");
    ref.on('child_added', function(data) {
      var id = data.key;
      var itemID = id;
      var itemName = data.val().item_name;
      var quantity = data.val().quantity;
      var isDeleted = data.val().isDeleted;

      itemName = itemName.replace(/\</g,"&lt;").replace(/\>/g,"&gt;");

      if(isDeleted == false){
        $("#"+id+"").dblclick(function() {
          document.getElementById("item_id").value = id;
          document.getElementById("submit").click();
        });
        var content = [itemID, itemName, quantity];
        inventoryItems.push(content);
      }
    });

    $('#itemTable').dataTable({
        "data": inventoryItems,
        "paging": true,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "searching": false,
        "ordering": true,
        "info": true,
        "autoWidth": false
    });
```

This is the code I have currently and I get a "No data available in table" result.

This is the array generated from the code above. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjypW.png

I'm unsure if its with the formatting of the area or reactjs and datatables simply don't match.

I hope you can help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share a bit more code with us? Maybe the get request and the component(s) that render(s) the data?

Comment: I've updated the question accordingly.